# Python: Obtain the 10 most important variables

Tags: python, random-forest, feature-selection

I have a data set that contains 368 independent variables, and I am currently using Random Forest Classification to determine which variables are the most important in explaining the behavior of the data. I've done this already in Python, and have found something like this as my result:

```
[(0.3748, 'var38'), (0.1738, 'var15'), (0.0294, 'saldo_medio_var5_ult3'), (0.0281, 'saldo_medio_var5_hace3'),...]
```

Results are obtained for all 368 variables. Trying to plot all of this on a graph would be unnecessary, so therefore, what I am attempting to do is to have Python list only the 10 most important variables.

How would I have Python do this, and how would I display this on a graph as well? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What makes them *important*?

Comment: The numbers to the left of the variable name. The higher the number, the more important that variable is in explaining the behavior of the data.

Comment: so basically  `lst.sort(reverse=True)` and take the first ten values returned?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the numbers are the importance, simply sort the list and slice out the first ten items.

```
variables.sort()
print variables[:10]
```